# Windows Server 2016 is Shutdown automatically

Tags: windows-server-2016

Hi I have a Windows Server 2016 VM running and it is shutdown automatically after some time,
here I don't know how to fix this issue and where is the problem.

Comment: The OS shuts down when it is not correctly activated, otherwise it would be good to know after how many minutes the shutdown happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it licensed then It depends on how you host your VM on which platform. There are several requirements, compatibilities and recommended specs.

VMware
https://partnerweb.vmware.com/comp_guide2/pdf/VMware_GOS_Compatibility_Guide.pdf
https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=software&testConfig=17
https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=software

Hyper-V
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt126277(v=ws.11).aspx

VBox
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/support/index.html

If it unlicensed then it will turn itself off usually every hour.

It is typical behavior of an unlicensed server - license it and it will stop doing that

Comment: in this server i checked windows is not activated

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons a VM to shut down. The first major step is to collect logs and to help your investigation of the "Why".

The best part to look at would be Windows Event Viewer. You'll want to click on "Windows Logs" then "System", then you can apply the filter for the Event Codes 1074, 6006, 6008. That will show you logs related to the shutdowns.

If you don't see anything check the logs of the Hypervisor Host.

---

As I said before there can be many reasons for a server to shutdown:

- Failed Activation
- Scheduled Tasks
- Update Restarts happening out of maintenance schedules
- Remote restart from RMM management software

The list can go on... The only way to know is to look at the logs.

[Spiceworks Issue related to shutdowns](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2092627-random-server-2012-r2-shutdowns)

[Mulcas: Instructions to Activate Windows](https://mulcas.com/windows-server-shuts-down-unexpectedly/)

###### Possible Duplicate of question: [Windows Server 2016 automatically restart](https://serverfault.com/q/947770/323938)